# 2 dimensional faithful quaternionic irreps of a finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, quaternions, characters

I am interested in finite groups with faithful 2 dimensional quaternionic irreps (finite subgroups of $ Sp_2 $).

Given a finite group $ G $ it is easy to find the character table (using GAP say) and from there determine the dimensions of its faithful complex irreps. From this information is there a way for me to determine the dimensions of its faithful quaternionic irreps?

Some background: the only groups with faithful 1 dimensional quaternionic irreps are

- all the cyclic groups $C_n$,
- all the dicyclic (also called binary dihedral) groups $Dic_{4n}$ of order $4n$,
- the binary tetrahedral group $2.A_4 \cong SL_2(3)$ of order $24$,
- the binary octahedral group $2.S_4 \cong GL_2(3)$ of order $48$,
- and the binary icosahedral group $2.A_5 \cong SL_2(5)$ of order $ 120 $

Comment: Look for a $4$-dimensional representation with Frobenius--Schur indicator $-$, or a $2$-dimensional representation with FS indicator $+$ or $0$.

Comment: You want the Frobenius-Schur indicator: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius%E2%80%93Schur_indicator

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I see that a faithful 4-dimensional representation with Frobenius-Schur indicator $ - $ corresponds to a subgroup of $ Sp_2 $. Could you explain in what way a 2 dimensional representation with FS indicator $ + $ or $ 0 $ corresponds to a subgroup of $ Sp_2 $?

Comment: Please do not use boldface in  your posts.

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira It looks from your post like you defined a quaternionic irrep to be a representation $G\to \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb H)$. Since $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb C)$ is a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb H)$, any $2$-dim complex rep yields a 2-dim quat rep. If it is irreducible over $\mathbb C$ and not of $-$ type, it remains irreducible over $\mathbb H$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde someone once told that my posts tend to be long and it might help if I put the key question in bold. Now it's become a bit of a habit even in shorter posts like this. You're right that it's unnecessary here I'll definitely remove the bold. In general is it considered impolite to use bold on MSE? If so I can stop doing it all together!

Comment: ${\rm Sp}(2)$ embeds in ${\rm SU}(4)$ and the finite subgroups of the latter are classified [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9905212.pdf). Their character tables can tell you which act irreducibly and quaternionically. Dunno how feasible this method is.

Comment: @runway44 That reference has a nice list of the irreducible subgroups of $ SU_4 $. One issue is that, with a handful of exceptions, the explicit matrix generators given there generate a group with center of size 4 (i.e. contains $ i $ times the identity). So every time it will say they are not quaternionic because $ Sp_2 $ contains $ -I $ but never $ iI $. Really you have bunch of central extension of the form $ 4.G $ for $ G $ a finite subgroup of $ PU_4 $ and $ 4.G $ will never be quaternionic even if $ 2.G $ might be. So it's a bit tricky to find the group $ 2.G $ and look at characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ G $ be a finite subgroup of $ Sp_2 $. That is equivalent to being a finite subgroup of $ GL_2(\mathbb{H}) $ the group of $ 2 \times 2 $ invertible quaternionic matrices. The finite subgroups of $ GL_2(\mathbb{H}) $ are classified in

https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82740228.pdf

There are a bunch of solvable subgroups, possibilities given on pages 477-478.

The quasisimple ones are $ SL_2(5) $ and $ SL_2(9) $.

Another interesting non solvable subgroup is $ \mathcal{B}^* $, the lift through the double cover $ Sp_2 \to SO_5 $ of the weyl group $ W(D_5) $ of determinant 1 signed permutation matrices. Also $ \mathcal{B} $, the commutator subgroup of $ \mathcal{B}^* $, is PerfectGroup(1920,6).

There are some variants on those groups also, but those are basically the most interesting ones.